# using update_attribute to update class attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using a code where for updating fields i have to use different methods based on some condition. code snippet looks like

```
   @issue = Issue.find(some_id) # Issue is ActiveRecord class

  if 'class fields' # some condition checking
    @issue.send("status").name = data     # status is a class and name is its attribute
    @issue.save
  else
    @issue.update_attribute("subject", data) # subject is a string
  end
```

i am looking for a solution where i can use update_attribute to update class attributes
for e.g.

```
@issue.update_attribute(@issue.:status.name, data) # invalid
```

may be i am doing some thing silly
but i want to know a better approach

thnx.

Comment: You are mixing up the meaning of _class_ with _instance_ here. Would be helpful if you would use the right wording. I don't understand what you are trying to do. What is the meaning of `issue.status.name`? How does your Issue model look like?

Comment: Issue class is a ActiveRecord class and it contains  belongs_to :status, :class_name => 'IssueStatus', :foreign_key => 'status_id' i just want to know how can i update status using Issue's object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` ( system.

In your Issue class your need define your status association like nested_attributes

```
class Issue < AR
  has_one :status
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :status
end
```

After you can update your status by

```
@issue.update_attribute({:status_attributes => {'name' => 'data'}})
```

PS : You can't do it on belongs_to associations.